# How to select object with multiple conditions that custom attributes are existed in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to initialize the value in hidden input in html. So I added attribute to inputs that I want to initialize. How to select these objects?

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" />

$("input:hidden[init]").val(""); // this is not working, but you might know what I want.
```

**[ADD]**

I'm using 1.4 jquery in Internet Explorer

Comment: Use `data-` attribute for custom attribute

Comment: Thanks~ It becomes clearer~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.

I write this code.

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" />
```

And I checked in IE, this converted like this

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" init="" />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" />
```

So, I did like this.

```
$("input:hidden[init=]").val("");
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Because `init` is an *attribute*, to select an element which has that attribute, you would put it *before* the `:hidden` jQuery psuedo-class, not after:

```js
$("input[init]:hidden").val("foo");
console.log(
  $("input[init]:hidden").val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" />
```

That said, when you want to add custom information to the HTML, it would be better to use `data-` attributes, rather than random non-standard attributes:

```js
$("input[data-init]:hidden").val("foo");
console.log(
  $("input[data-init]:hidden").val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" data-init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" data-init/>
```

For older versions of jQuery, `:hidden` may not work as expected - use a standard selector string instead:

```
input[data-init][type='hidden']
```

```js
$("input[data-init][type='hidden']").val("foo");
console.log(
  $("input[data-init][type='hidden']").val()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" data-init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" data-init/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not working. I think because of version. My company is using 1.4.1 version JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use this `$("input[type='hidden'][init]");`

```js
console.log("control found with init attribute : " + $("input[type='hidden'][init]").length);
console.log("control found without init attribute : " + $("input[type='hidden']:not([init])").length);
console.log("All Hiddens : " + $("input[type='hidden']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="a" value="" init />
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="b" value="" />
```